# Make call to web api using impersonation

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api2, windows-server-2012

Im trying to have one api running on server A, not on a domain, call to another api B that is on a domain.  Im making the call using impersionation.  The api on B is under windows auth.

To test the impersonation, I built a small windows utility to run from A (not on the domain), and this works. The impersonation is using logontype 9
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

However, when I run the same code but within an web api hosted on iis on A, nothing seems to come through to B.

The api running in IIS server A, is running under an app pool using the app pool identity.  However, the code that actually makes a request to api on B, is using impersonation.

Could the app pool identity on A be interfering with the call to B?

Comment: [mcve] might get you an answer, or at least posting some code.

Comment: Why don't you try it?  Change the app pool identity to be the one that you used to test the process and see if it works.  In the old days you would need to revertToSelf to get to the base process token before impersonation but I don't think this works and more.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be with setting up SPNs and Kerbros Constrained Delegation appropriately.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2017/01/13/constrained-kerberos-delegation-with-asp-net/

Applications running within the context of IIS server are not allowed to willy-nilly access resources on the corporate network. The HTTP Service running on Server A needs to be set up in a way that it has rights to impersonate and access resources on Server B.

When you say that server A not on domain, I assume that server A is on a different Windows Domain. In order to allow cross-domain calls to go through, you will need to have a trust relationship between domains.

The Domain offering access to a resource, must "Trust" the domain consuming the resource.